# Batch input from DataFrame in Neural Network

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, neural-network

I am executing the following code in the final block of my regression code:

```
steps = 50000

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(steps):

        sess.run(train, feed_dict={X_data:X_train,y_target:y_train})



        if i%500 == 0:

            rand_ind = np.random.random_integers(len(X_test)+1)

            feed = {X_data:X_test.iloc[rand_ind:rand_ind+8,:],y_target:y_test.iloc[rand_ind:rand_ind+8,:]}

            loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y_target-y_output))/8
            print(sess.run(loss,feed_dict=feed))
```

Is this a good way to generate smaller batches from a pandas DataFrame or are there better ways to do so?

I am using iloc here, as before I was not able to index properly. Yet I am getting the following error:

```
DeprecationWarning: This function is deprecated. Please call randint(1, 6193 + 1) instead from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
```

Comment: As error say use `rand_ind =np.random.randint(len(X_test)+1)`

Comment: Thank You, that helped already. Is this a good way to select a batch from a Dataframe or can you maybe refer to a better one?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select random rows from the dataframe you could use the following code:

```
import numpy as np 
batch = df.iloc[np.random.choice(df.index.values, sample_size)]
```

This code will select random rows indices and then will select them for the batch. replace sample_size with the size of the batch.

If you will use it multiple times you will create a random sample with return over your data.

If you don't wont to re use the same exmples, you can use this code to sample and then drop the rows you samples and not use them again

```
import numpy as np
sample =  np.random.choice(df.index.values, sample_size)
batch = df.iloc[sample]
newdf = df.drop(sample, axis = 0)
```